# How to enable “on-the-fly” autocompletion?

Tags: autocompletion

How can I make it so that no command or extra keystroke is required for the autocompletion menu to pop up?

i.e. what I want is the menu to be always present while in insert mode and to be constantly updating its suggestions as I type.

Comment: Supertab is not an auto-completion plugin. Which auto-completion plugin are you using?

Comment: Well none, then. I mean the usual Ctrl-n type menu.

Comment: I found this solution, which seems to (kind of) work for me, see the link below. However, the noinsert/noselect options do not seem to have any effect, why is that? (I can't comment there for lack of rep :/ )      https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15733/auto-activate-autocompletion?rq=1

Comment: You can use `set completeopt?` to see if this option is correctly set. Some other plugins or settings may override this option

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a  super simple solution, you can add the code from this page to your .vimrc.
https://gist.github.com/maxboisvert/a63e96a67d0a83d71e9f49af73e71d93

There is also a plugin version of it which can be found here.
https://github.com/maxboisvert/vim-simple-complete

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally using https://github.com/maralla/completor.vim for this, it's very lightweight and requires no configuration to work. It doesn't do any fancy stuff or alter what's shown in the completion pop-up in any way, it will simply auto show the completion pop-up whenever it can.

I'm also using these settings for it, to make it more ergonomical:

```
" Select autocomplete item with Tab
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-Y>" : "\<Tab>"

" Don't autoselect an item from the completion menu, and always show the menu
let g:completor_complete_options='menuone,noinsert'

" No delay on showing the completion pop-up
let g:completor_completion_delay=0
```